# Lazy loading with react route v4 issues

Tags: reactjs

Found the below error when I tried lazy loading (connected components) with react route

Element Type is invalid:expected string ( for built-in components) or class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Comment: Please add code associated

Comment: Share some code what you have tried, it will help us to give you a right solution

Comment: Tried this one ? https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16332#issuecomment-336925116